# CakePHP: isolating AJAX pagination loading to a <div>, not entire .ctp file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and the jQuery script from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`. The problem I'm having is that upon the AJAX call to reload the `<div id="part2">` of the page, it reloads the entire page (`test_page.ctp`) inside of `<div id="part2">`. How do I isolate the update to `<div id="part2">` and have only `<div id="part2">` portion of `test_page.ctp` loaded?

CakePHP code in `test_page.ctp`:

```
// at the beginning of cpt file
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'evalScripts' => true,
    'update' => '#part2',
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeIn', array('speed' => 'fast')),
    'complete' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeOut', array('speed' => 'fast'))
));

// at the very end of ctp file
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Layout of my page (`.../controller_name/test_page`) on initial load:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|  <div id="part1">...</div>  |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|  <div id="part2">           |
|   ...                       |
|  <previous> 1 2.. 5 <next>  |
|  </div>                     |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Layout of my page (`.../controller_name/test_page`) on after moving onto another page:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|  <div id="part1">...</div>  |
|  this <div> is not reloaded |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|  <div id="part2">           |
|      <div id="part1">       |
|          entire next page   |
|      </div>                 |
|  </div>                     |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

I have a problem where the AJAX call inserts the entire `test_page.ctp` into `<div id="part2">` when I just want `<div id="part2">` to be updated with its content only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make another `.ctp` file that contains/generates the content you would like to render. Then render that file within an `ajax` layout. The `ajax` layout is essentially an empty layout that just outputs the contents of your `.ctp` file. This is how it works:

```
-----------------------------
|    OuterSection is your   |
|    Layout                 |
|  -----------------------  |
|  | Inner Section is    |  |
|  | your view file      |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  -----------------------  |
|---------------------------|
```

This is how rendering works and it is there to separate a website's layout from all of its different pages.
To render within the `ajax` layout in cake 1.3 use:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

within the controller function you're calling with your AJAX call.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand what you mean by rendering another `.ctp` file within an `ajax` layout. I see that the `ajax` layout outputs HTML with no styling. Can you walk me through with this?

Comment: When you make an AJAX call to the server it responds with something. In your case you need some HTML returned. To return that HTML you need to render it of course. Create an file called `ajax.ctp` in `app/view/layout/`. It must contain only `<?php echo $content_for_layout;?>`. Then set the layout to `ajax` - the one you just created and make the ajax call again. You must use this layout in whatever controller function you'd like to use AJAX.

Comment: My `test_page.ctp` needs to the have the `default` layout. It contains `div`s `part1` and `part2`. I want `part2` to be updated upon moving onto another page. I'm understanding that I need to set `$this->layout = 'ajax'` in controller action `test_page()`? But that's not what I want. In your diagram, I have two `div`s in the `Inner Section` you have labeled. I'd like `part2` of the `Inner Section` to be updated only. Do I need to somehow call another view from `test_page.ctp`?

Comment: You have two options - use ajax or use a reusable view aka `element`.
Check the docs on that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just moved this code to the `layout` and it worked fine :

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'evalScripts' => true,
    'update' => '#part2',
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeIn', array('speed' => 'fast')),
    'complete' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeOut', array('speed' => 'fast'))
));
```